# SPSS Selecting some cases while excluding others

Tags: spss

I am trying to select multiple cases and exclude some in my data in SPSS. I have different department numbers and I want to exclude dept 0133 and 0083 all while only selecting that course level equal 100 and 200 level courses. Is this possible to do in one selection? (Note: dept is a string variable)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what if some cases have dept 0133 and course level 100 ? Do youplan to keep them or not ?

Comment: If they are course level 100 but have dept 0133 I want them excluded. Sorry for not clarifying. The exclusion of those two departments trumps the course level.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this should do it:

```
select if any(level, 100, 200) and not any(dept,'0133','0083').
```